# Android AutoCompleteTextbox

Tags: android, autocomplete, autocompletetextview

I am trying to implement a functionality like Twitter: when user type in '@', a dropdown menu shows-up with some suggestions.

Here's my current code:

```
mTextBox = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
String[] testArray = {"aaa", "aabc", "aaaa", "bbb" , "bcd", "zzz", "fff", "ndc"};

ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = 
            new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, testArray);

adapter.setNotifyOnChange(true);

mTextBox.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Currently, the behavior of the AutoCompleteTextView is, when I type in part of the word, the full suggestion shows up. For example, when I type in `a`, it shows nothing, when I type in `aa`, then it shows suggestion of `aabc`, `aaa` and `aaaa`.

How can I make it so when I type in `@`, it shows a list of all available options?

Thank you

Comment: U can use Listpopupwindow to create ur own control and have full control over this

Comment: Try to make your own custom widget. Check this link it might be usefulhttp://techdroid.kbeanie.com/2010/04/custom-autocomplete-for-android.html

Answer (score 1):

Add the following attribute into your AutocompleteTextView of xml file

`android:completionThreshold="1"`